# How make teasers appear upon an image and not behind

Tags: html, css

I have two sections -> hero and teaser, and in the teaser section i need make the teasers pictures appear just a bit upon the hero section, but z-index, position relative and top -1 is not working, i believe this is happening because i am using overflow: hidden, i already try use z-index but is not working.

The code is a bit extensive, so i create a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwBMZQ).

This is what i want:

This is what is happening:

I cant use CSS3, just 2, unfortunately..

HTML:

```
<section class="hero">
    </section>
    <section class="teasers">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="teaser">
          <img class="teaser__image" src="public/images/main/teasers/pubcrawl.jpg" />
          <div class="teaser__content">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="teaser">
          <img class="teaser__image" src="public/images/main/teasers/diversao.jpg" />
          <div class="teaser__content">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="teaser">
          <img class="teaser__image" src="public/images/main/teasers/crawlers.jpg" />
          <div class="teaser__content">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="teaser">
          <img class="teaser__image" src="public/images/main/teasers/staff.jpg" />
          <div class="teaser__content">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .container has a style of `overflow:hidden` if you remove that you can see the overflow...

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoBgER

Comment: yeah, but is wrong take of the overflow, because the content will be outside of .container, check out with devtools.

Comment: i am going to accept your answer because in some way you help me, i need take of the overflow in the .hero .container, not in .teasers, please, update your answer.

Comment: what wrong context? i did several advanced courses in lynda, treehouse and pluralsight, this is how i learned..

Comment: you are not helping, if you want say that my code is wrong, please explain why...